# How to get equalized dataset from 7 different datasets in one dimension

Tags: matlab, equality

I have 7 different datasets in one dimension ,they have the same data length,they are stored in column vector respectively as below:
[dataset in column vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHb0f.png)

What I want is get the equalized datasets of the 7 different column vectors,can you tell me what function should I use in matlab?

Comment: What does "equalized" mean?

Comment: are you searching for the same values in a row or in a column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for reshape function?